# How to remove, certain part of the code from many php files.

Tags: php, html, list

I am new to php, I have created many files and now I need to remove, certain part of the code from many php files. I know this question sounds familiar, but i need a very basic and simple explanation, just like a beginner.

```
<li style="opacity: 1;" class="span3">
    <div class="thumbnail"><a href="cd_sticker_printing_sticker.php" class="thumb"><img src="brochure/cdstickercoverprinting/sticker/1 (3).jpg" alt="Product"></a>
      <p><a href="cd_sticker_printing_sticker.php">STICKER</a></p>
      <p class="price"><span>€ 1.230</span></p>
      <p class="rating"><i class="icon-star"><span>1</span></i><i class="icon-star"><span>2</span></i><i class="icon-star"><span>3</span></i><i class="icon-star"><span>4</span></i><i class="icon-star-empty"><span>5</span></i></p>
      <a href="enquiry.php"><input value="For Enquiry" class="btn" type="button"></a>
      <a href="#" class="add-list"><i class="icon-star"></i>Wish List</a><a href="#" class="add-comp"><i class="icon-tasks"></i>Compare</a></div>
  </li>
```

I need to remove `<p class="rating"><i class="icon-star"><span>1</span></i><i class="icon-star"><span>2</span></i><i class="icon-star"><span>3</span></i><i class="icon-star"><span>4</span></i><i class="icon-star-empty"><span>5</span></i></p>` and `<a href="#" class="add-list"><i class="icon-star"></i>Wish List</a><a href="#" class="add-comp"><i class="icon-tasks"></i>Compare</a>` from the above list

Comment: Do you have sublime editor? It can be done by this.

Comment: What program are you using to edit your code? Most will have a find and replace tool. You must search for the code you wish to remove (one piece at a time) by copying it into the 'find' part and then run the 'replace all' command. If you are unsure how to bring up the your editor's "find and replace' tool, you will need to Google "<the name of your editor> find and replace in files"

Comment: For future reference you can use include("yourfile.ext") and have the contents of that file dumped where you make the call. Then, if it needs to change you can edit it all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a backup before running this, but a php answer would be:

```
$directory_with_files = "your\\directory"; 
$string_to_replace = '<li style="opacity: 1;" class="span3">
    <div class="thumbnail"><a href="cd_sticker_printing_sticker.php" class="thumb"><img src="brochure/cdstickercoverprinting/sticker/1 (3).jpg" alt="Product"></a>
      <p><a href="cd_sticker_printing_sticker.php">STICKER</a></p>
      <p class="price"><span>€ 1.230</span></p>
      <p class="rating"><i class="icon-star"><span>1</span></i><i class="icon-star"><span>2</span></i><i class="icon-star"><span>3</span></i><i class="icon-star"><span>4</span></i><i class="icon-star-empty"><span>5</span></i></p>
      <a href="enquiry.php"><input value="For Enquiry" class="btn" type="button"></a>
      <a href="#" class="add-list"><i class="icon-star"></i>Wish List</a><a href="#" class="add-comp"><i class="icon-tasks"></i>Compare</a></div>
  </li>';

//Get the files in the directory
$files = scandir($directory_with_files);

//Get rid of ".." and "." as files.
unset($files[0]);
unset($files[1]);

//Loop through them
foreach($files as $file){

   //read the entire string
   $str=file_get_contents($directory_with_files."\\".$file);

   //replace something in the file string - this is a VERY simple example
   $str=str_replace("$string_to_replace","",str);

   //write the entire string
   file_put_contents($directory_with_files."\\".$file, $str);
}//end foreach loop
```

I haven't run this so you'll probably have to debug something here and there.

Also, in the future, you might find it easier to use include("yourfile.ext) a single time and not have to edit each page. When you advance along a little more you'll probably use a view to call on page markup like this.